# Custom migration from external DB

Tags: drush, 8, migrations

I'm trying to migrate content from an Expression Engine database to Drupal 8.

I set up a `$databases['migrate']['default']` in settings.php and copied and modified *BeerNode.php* from *migrate_plus migrate_example* module in a custom module.
This is my query code in BlogNode.php.

```
  public function query() {
    // $this->configuration['ignore_map'] = true;
    $query = $this->select('exp_weblog_titles', 'tab1');
    $query->addField('tab1', 'entry_id', 'bid');
    $query->addField('tab1', 'title', 'name');
    $query->addField('tab2', 'field_id_10', 'body');
    $query->innerJoin('exp_weblog_data', 'tab2', 'tab1.entry_id = tab2.entry_id');
    $query->condition('tab1.weblog_id', 10, '=');
    return $query;
  }
```

Now Drush complains about a missing column:

> Migration failed with source plugin exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'b.bid' in 'on clause':
>
> ```
> SELECT tab1.entry_id AS bid, tab1.title AS name, tab2.field_id_196 AS body, map.sourceid1 AS migrate_map_sourceid1, map.source_row_status AS
> migrate_map_source_row_status
> FROM
> {exp_weblog_titles} tab1
> INNER JOIN {exp_weblog_data} tab2 ON tab1.entry_id = tab2.entry_id
> LEFT OUTER JOIN destinationdatabase.migrate_map_blog_node map ON b.bid = map.sourceid1
> WHERE  (tab1.weblog_id = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND( (map.sourceid1 IS NULL ) OR (map.source_row_status = :db_condition_placeholder_1) );
> ```

This is the implementation of getIds():

```
  public function getIds() {
    return array(
      'bid' => array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'alias' => 'b',
      ),
    );
  }
```

I assume that the second part of the query should be `ON tab1.entry_id = map.sourceid1` but I can't set anything other than `bid`.

I kind of resolved by temporarily setting `$this->configuration['ignore_map'] = true;` before the query losing some traking functionality though.

Comment: In your source you'll have an implementation of getIds(), can you post that here?

Comment: Yes, **b** was coming from there, I edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'alias' => 'b', from your getIds() call, that parameter is only needed if you need to remove any ambiguity from the source query.